# Java Game Engine

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-engine

Does anybody know any good 2D game engines for Java? I'd like one that at least tries to keep up-to-date. I tried using JGame, but it didn't have the flexibility I required. I tried using Slick2D, but it doesn't offer an easy solution for collision detection. Instead, most people suggest you loop through all of your entities and check if you entered another object that way, but O(n) seems like a really, really horrible way to go about that when you plan on having several enemies, boundaries, bullets flying everywhere...

Also, the creator of Slick2D hardly ever updates anymore, a lot of the tutorials in the Wiki aren't even completed. I'm not blaming him, I understand what it feels like when you don't have time, but surely there's a framework out there like what I'm looking for?

Comment: O(n) horrible for several? I think it's perfectly fine and fast for hundreds of enemies.

Comment: Hm, I wonder how many enemies would be required for O(n) to create noticeable lag...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://www.lwjgl.org/) sounds very interesting. I've never used myself, but they have a [nice list of projects using their engine](http://www.lwjgl.org/projects.php), and from what I'm quite sure I saw in their files, the [Revenge of the Titans](http://www.puppygames.net/revenge-of-the-titans/) game uses this lib.

The [Slick](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) lib also seems interesting, it works on top of LWJGL.

Comment: I didn't know that Revenge of the titans was using Java at all, excelent game!

Comment: Slick2D works on top of LWJGL.

Comment: @TomA adding it right now

Comment: Instead of editing your answer, you should vote to close the question - it's off topic as it's asking for an external resource. And seriously, taking 4 years to reply to a comment? Why bother at all?

Answer (score 1):

I only know 3 2D Java game engines: the aforementioned Slick and JGame, as well as GLib (theglibengine.wordpress.com). The last one, GLib, is fairly new and rather buggy but it handles all collision detection for you. Have you considered GameMaker(yoyogames.com)? It's rather good, has a powerful free version, and requires no programming for most games.